# Network intermittently fails to come up during boot

Tags: boot, networking, 22.04

I have a PC with Ubuntu 22.04 Server as the OS. I chose to encrypt the OS drive with LUKS, and installed dropbear to ssh into the machine during boot and unlock the drive. This only works intermittently: about half the time, even though the monitor attached to the machine shows "starting dropbear", I cannot ssh into the computer, nor ping it, no matter how long I wait. This seems to indicate some problem with the network interface and its timing during boot, but I have no idea where to start troubleshooting. Any ideas?

Also, just noticed that the last output before dropbear is started is IP-Config on the correct ethernet interface. It finishes with `IP-Config: "ethernet_interface_name" complete`, and proceeds to list the IP and other parameters of the interface. At the same time, I cannot ping the computer on that same static IP.

Here is some of the last output I see, with an IP-Config interleaved with the unlock disk prompt:

```
Please unlock disk dm-crypt-0: Ip-Config:enp7s0 guessed broadcast address 192.168.9.255
IP-Config:enp7s0 complete:
 address: 192.168.0.70    broadcast: 192.168.0.255    netmask: 255.255.255.0
 gateway: 192.168.0.254   dns0     : 0.0.0.0          dns1   : 0.0.0.0
 host: mynas
 rootserver: 0.0.0.0 rootpath:
 filename  :
```

This is followed by another IP-Config on the other ethernet NIC I have in the PC, returning identical results. Finally, there is these lines:

```
no search or nameservers found in /run/net-enp6s0.conf /run/net-enp6s0.conf /run/net-enp7s0.conf /run/net6-*.conf
Begin: Starting dropbear ...
```

My apologies for any possible typos, as I am typing this by hand from the output I see on the screen. Thanks for looking.

Comment: You can see startup logs for each boot (`sudo journalctl  --list-boots`) with `sudo journalctl  -b #` (replace `#` with the boot number). Read `man journalctl `.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know approximately what I'm looking for, e.g. "Networking" or something else? Also, I updated the question with some possibly pertinent information.

Comment: You're looking for another understanding of how neteorking is started, how dropbear is started, how failures differ from. successes.

Comment: BTW, you didn't add "some possibly pertinent information". Show the IPs, show the error messages

Comment: There are no error messages that I can see on the boot screen. I'm in the process of looking through the logs, but there's almost two thousand lines and I don't know what everything means. If you must see the actual IP, I can provide it, not that I see how it will help understand what's wrong when it works at some times and not at others (yes, the boot screen output appears to be the same regardless).